# "background-size: cover" not working correctly.

Tags: html, css

I've done this almost a million times but it's been a while and I cannot get it to work for some reason.

My HTML file consists of nothing but an empty body tag. Here's my css:

```
body{
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    background-image: image-url("background.jpg");
    background-size: cover; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

The width stretches/shrinks to fit the window perfectly, but the height refuses to. Here's what happens when I shrink the browser window:

[image: background]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The width and height are not necessary from experience.  Have you a jsfiddle link?

Comment: are you sure that your body covers all the page?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides that appears to be the problem. I just put a border on the body and it is only spanning a fraction of the page. How can I expand it to the size of the browser window without filling it with content since apparently `height: 100%` is not working.

Comment: @ByronS percentage height only works if the parent element has a height specified. Try `html { height: 100%; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
html, 
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

The body does not cover the rest of your page.